# Add function result to database

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am using the following code to generate random numbers. With the probability of getting lower numbers higher than getting high numbers.

```
function fun() {
        $num = mt_rand(1, 100);
        if ($num > 0 && $num <= 90) {
            $return = mt_rand(10, 45) / 10;  // 90%
        } else if ($num > 90 && $num <= 98) {
            $return = mt_rand(45, 100) / 10;  // 8%
        } else {
            $return = mt_rand(100, 200) / 10;  // 2%
        }
        return sprintf("%01.1f",$return);
    }
```

However my coding experience is very basic, I am essentially teaching myself and I am unsure as to how to get the result of this function into a form that I could then add to my database..

I know the below won't make sense but maybe it will make my goal clearer..

```
$interest = (the result of fun()) 
mysql_query("UPDATE r$game[0]_$tab[pimp] SET suisseint=$interest WHERE id=$user1no[id];");
```

Thank you!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to get the result of function fun into my database..

$interest = echo fun();  doesn't show anything.

The function itself works fine.

Comment: `$interest = fun();` no `echo`

Comment: `r$game[0]_$tab[pimp]` curios table name

Comment: Thank you Dagon! The table name is because you can play more than 1 game at a time. So game[0] refers to the game "round" the user is currently in. Again, thank you for your help. It's so frustrating when you spend hours trying to figure something out and its one word "echo" holding you back haha!

Comment: i wouldn't have a table per game, just the game id in a single table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid mysql API as it is deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Use the mysqli extension instead.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$mysql = array(
    'host' => 'http://myhost.com',
    'user' => 'my_username',
    'pass' => 'secret',
    'dbname' => 'my_database'
);
$interest = fun();
$conx = mysqli_connect($mysql['host'], $mysql['user'], $mysql['pass'], $mysql['dbname']);
if (mysqli_query($conx, "UPDATE r$game[0]_$tab[pimp] SET suisseint=$interest WHERE id=$user1no[id]")) {
    // celebrate
} else {
    // give an error message
}
```

Obviously the $mysql array (or whatever you call it) should be set up in a script location that is appropriate to be used as configuration info for other scripts that will use the database.

Lots more info on the mysqli API at http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Note that this is the simplest approach. It assumes no data provided by a user. Typically *preparing* your statement is considered better practice, but this is the quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't realise all of that about mysqli! Thank you! Big help!